# How to set relation foreign key to be required

Tags: loopbackjs

I have two models. Company and Booking.
In the relation part of model Company

```
"bookings": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "Booking",
  "foreignKey": "companyId"
}
```

The issue is, it is possible to post a Booking without companyId which is not ok.
From the explorer.

```
Booking {
  bookingId (string, optional),
  name (string),
  location (string),
  companyId (string, optional)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually can't enforce this particular validation out-of-the-box. Instead you have a couple different options:

a) You can enforce the creation of Booking through company through the endpoint, `POST /api/Company/{id}/Bookings` by disabling `Booking.disableRemoteMethod('create', ...)` along with any other methods that have the ability to create records from the `Booking` model.

b) You can add a remote hook to check whether or not the company record exists and throw an error accordingly.

```
Booking.beforeRemote('create', function(ctx, booking, next) {
  var Company = Booking.app.models.Company;
  var companyId = ctx.req.body.companyId;

  if (companyId) {
    errorMsg = 'Company with id=' + companyId + ' does not exist.';
    var noCompany = new Error(errorMsg);
    Company.findById(companyId, function(err, company) {
      if (err) next(err);
      if (!company) {
        ctx.res.statusCode = 400;
        next(noCompany);
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

You will also have to do the same thing for any other endpoints that allow record create such as `PUT /api/Bookings`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the companyId property explicitly in the booking.json file, and add the required:true property. It would look like

```
{
    "properties": {
        "companyId": {
            "type": "number",
            "required": true
        },
        ... //other properties
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that this solves the validation issue. What happens when a company with the `id` you provided doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

In richardpringle's [answer part b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084218/7963464) `booking` was an empty object for me.

I was able to get this answer to work by adding `app` to the booking.js file like below:

```
'use strict';
var app = require('../../server/server');

module.exports = function(Booking) {
  Booking.beforeRemote('create', function(ctx, booking, next) {
    var Company = app.models.Company;
    var companyId = ctx.req.body.companyId;

    if (companyId) {
      errorMsg = 'Company with id=' + companyId + ' does not exist.';
      var noCompany = new Error(errorMsg);
      Company.findById(companyId, function(err, company) {
        if (err) next(err);
        if (!company) {
          ctx.res.statusCode = 400;
          next(noCompany);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
};
```

- line 2 is new
- line 6 is modified from richardpringle's answer

  - From: `var Company = Booking.app.models.Company;`
  - To: `var Company = app.models.Company;`