# Loopback : One model having multiple relations with other models

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

## Use Case

1. An Organisation has many leave types.
2. An Employee of the Organisation has many Leaves.
3. A Leave has a single leave type.

So, as an employee when I apply for a leave, the leave should conform to the LeaveType that has been defined by the Organisation.

## Problem

The LeaveType model has a 'Belongs to' relationship with both Leave and Organisation models and hence does not behave as intended.

### Relations

These are the relations defined in the model.json file.

#### LeaveType

```
"organization": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "Organization",
  "foreignKey": ""
},
"leave": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "Leave",
  "foreignKey": ""
}
```

#### Organisation

```
"leaveTypes": {
  "type": "hasMany",
  "model": "LeaveType",
  "foreignKey": ""
}
```

#### Leave

```
"employee": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "Employee",
  "foreignKey": ""
},
"leaveType": {
  "type": "hasOne",
  "model": "LeaveType",
  "foreignKey": ""
}
```

P.S: I'm using mongoDB for persistence.

Comment: What is the desired behavior, your question says they're not behaving as expected, but what do you expect, is there an error?

Comment: Well, when I query the leaves of the employees, I would want to use the 'include' filter to display the leave type as well. Right now it's null since it doesn't seem to be getting mapped to the Leave model.

Comment: Is the foreign key that's supposed to link them together there? You've to set it for the relations to have something to hold them together, and there're multiple ways to handle this mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080231/how-to-set-relation-foreign-key-to-be-required
Also, I understand foreign key is created based on model names, but it's better to set it as it'd making developing things a bit easier.